# Extract #text part of XML using Powershell

Tags: xml, powershell, parsing

I'm trying to extract weather information out of a bureau of meteorology XML page using Powershell; from all the tutorials I've watched, and followed, not one of them explains how to extract the contents of the text part of an element, example:

In the example code below, I'm after extracting the text "Sunny" and "High" from the "forecast" and "fire_danger" attributes. The path to get to "forecast-period" is: `product/forecast/area/forecast-period` the following code is out of the XML that I'm trying to extract content from:  `<forecast-period index="1" start-time-local="2022-07-17T00:00:00+08:00">                 <text type="forecast">Sunny</text> <text type="fire_danger"><p>High</p>`

As you can see,  there's text "Sunny" and "High", I'm trying to extrct them out individually.

PS: I've also tried InnerText, InnerXML etc, but this seems to extraxt all other child elements, I'd like to [1] index to the first one or even the second one.

Thank you,

Comment: `([xml]'<text type="forecast">Weather content here</text>').Text.'#text'`?

Comment: Hi, that's close.  In the example code below, I'm after extracting the text "Sunny" and "High" from the "forecast" and "fire_danger" attributes.  The path to get to "forecast-period" is: `product/forecast/area/forecast-period`

`<forecast-period index="1" start-time-local="2022-07-17T00:00:00+08:00">
                <text type="forecast">Sunny</text>
                <text type="fire_danger">
                    <p>High</p>`

I guess I'm after away of narrowing in on those nodes, and extracting the relevent text.  thanks.

Comment: Based on your given path, it would be: `$xml.product.forecast.area.'forecast-period'.Text.'#text'. But I doubt if the path you supplied is correct.  Please, [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/73021268/edit) the question and put that / a [mcve] in there.

Comment: Your above suggestion has nearly worked, it's very close to what I'm after, thank you. now all I need is to select the object eq to type="forecast" and type="fire_danger" so I can pull them out individually, as it currently pulls all text nodes out as one continuous sentence. I'll edit my above question to try and better suit the requirement, thanks.

Comment: You can simply index a property: `$xml.product.forecast.area.'forecast-period'[0].Text.'#text'` or the returned list of strings: `$xml.product.forecast.area.'forecast-period'.Text.'#text'[0]`.

Comment: Please, next time, put all the information and exact question in the question itself: [After you post, leave the question open in your browser for a bit, and see if anyone comments. If you missed an obvious piece of information, be ready to respond **by editing your question** to include it. If someone posts an answer, be ready to try it out and provide feedback!](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to be able to answer you more specifically and so that others can leverage from your question.

Comment: Thank you very much Ron, I believe this has resolved my questions. If I have any more in future I'll post again with more detail as you've recommended.  Than you.